# Detect when multiprocessing queue is empty and closed

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Let's say I have two processes: a reader and a writer. How does the writer detect when the reader has finished writing values?

The `multiprocessing` module has [a queue with a close method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.close) that seems custom-built for this purpose. But how do you detect when the queue has been closed?

This doesn't seem to work, as the writer never exits:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def getter(q):
    while True:
        try:
            print(q.get())
        except Exception:
            break

def putter(q):
    q.put(1)
    q.put(2)
    q.close()

q = mp.Queue()
writer = mp.Process(target=putter, args=(q, ))
reader = mp.Process(target=getter, args=(q, ))
reader.start()
writer.start()

writer.join()
reader.join()
```

Should the reader-writer pair use a sentinel value to signal end of writing? Then what's the point of having the `close` method?

EDIT: While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605188/communicating-end-of-queue) asks about the Queue module (now [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html)), I am asking specifically about `mp.Queue` and what the correct use of the `.close` method is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Communicating end of Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605188/communicating-end-of-queue)

Comment: @Turn I'm specifically asking about `mp.Queue` which has a `.close` method. I know that this question has been asked previously about the `queue` module (formerly Queue in python 2), but both the implementation and the interfaces for these modules differ.

Comment: Fair enough, I retracted the vote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But how do you detect when the queue has been closed?

You don't. That is not the purpose of `close`. Calling `close` doesn't even guarantee that no more items will be added to the queue; the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.close) say

> Indicate that no more data will be put on this queue **by the current process**.

`close` is intended to shut down the current process's feeder thread for that queue (or at least start shutting it down), not to communicate an end-of-queue to other processes.

---

If you want to signal that no more values will be written to the queue, use standard techniques like enqueueing a sentinel object, like you would with an ordinary `queue.Queue`.