# Python multiprocessing: How to start processes that depend on each other?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a basic question that ragards the Python multiprocessing method, how different processes, which use queues to transfer data, could optimally be started.

For that I use a simple example where

1. Data is received
2. Data is processed
3. Data is send

All of the upper steps should happen in parallel through three different processes.

Here the example code:

```
import multiprocessing
import keyboard
import time

def getData(queue_raw):
    for num in range(1000):
        queue_raw.put(num)
        print("getData: put "+ str(num)+" in queue_raw")
    while True:
        if keyboard.read_key() == "s":
            break

def calcFeatures(queue_raw, queue_features):
    while not queue_raw.empty():
        data = queue_raw.get()
        queue_features.put(data**2)
        print("calcFeatures: put "+ str(data**2)+" in queue_features")

def sendFeatures(queue_features):
    while not queue_features.empty():
        feature = queue_features.get()
        print("sendFeatures: put "+ str(feature)+" out")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    queue_raw = multiprocessing.Queue()
    queue_features = multiprocessing.Queue()

    processes = [

        multiprocessing.Process(target=getData, args=(queue_raw,)),
        multiprocessing.Process(target=calcFeatures, args=(queue_raw, queue_features,)),
        multiprocessing.Process(target=sendFeatures, args=(queue_features,))
    ]

    processes[0].start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    processes[1].start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    processes[2].start()

    #for p in processes:
    #    p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

This program works, but my question is regarding the start of the different processes.
Ideally `process[1]` should start only if `process[0]` put data in the `queue_raw`; while `process[2]` should only start if `process[1]` put the calculated features in `queue_features`.

Right now I did that through `time.sleep()` function, which is suboptimal, since I don't necessarily know how long the processes will take.
I also tried something like:

```
processes[0].start()
while queue_raw.empty():
    time.sleep(0.5)
processes[1].start()
```

But it won't work, since only the first process is estimated. Any method how this process depending starts could be done?

Comment: Start all the processes and design them as a loop of infinite sleep unless there is some work to do (data found in the respective queue)?

Comment: `Queue.get()` should block if there is no data in the queue. Are you sure you need to sleep there? (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get)

Comment: @moooeeeep Yes, based on the documentation this would not be the case. But if I leave the sleep statements out, the program rather does not execute the other processes, or it does it, but since the queue is still empty the processes are already finished.
Also the keyboard break then does not work.

I tested the same also without the print statements, but it still won't work. So I think I am generally missing a basic concept how processes are started when the passed queues are interchangeably used between the processes

Comment: You should change the exit condition to `while True` then, or check some other flag to notify processes to exit.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48569731/detect-when-multiprocessing-queue-is-empty-and-closed

Comment: Thanks for your comment @moooeeeep. That solved the problem. I put the answer in pseudo code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@moooeeeep pointed out the right comment.
Checking with `while not queue.empty():` is not waiting till data is actually in the queue!

An approach via a sentinel object (here `None`) and a `while True` loop  will enforce that the process waits till the other processes put data in the queue:

```
FLAG_STOP=False
while FLAG_STOP is False:
    data = queue_raw.get()  # get will wait
    if data is None:
        # Finish analysis
        FLAG_STOP = True
    else:
        # work with data
```